# How can I test output of non-ASCII characters using Sphinx doctest?

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, python-sphinx, non-ascii-characters, doctest

I'm at a loss how to test printing output that includes non-ASCII characters using Sphinx doctest.

When I have test that include code that generates non-ASCII characters, or that contains expected results that include non-ASCII characters, I get encoding errors.

For example, if I have:

```
def foo():
    return 'γ'
```

then a doctest including

```
>>> print(foo())
```

will produce an error of the form

> Encoding error:
>   'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u03b3' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

as will any test of the form

```
>>> print('')
γ
```

Only by ensuring that none of my functions whose results I'm attempting to `print`, and none of the expected printed results, contain such characters can I avoid these errors. As a result I've had to disable many important tests.

At the head of all my code I have

```
# encoding: utf8
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

and (in desperation) I've tried things like

```
doctest_global_setup =(
    '#encoding: utf8\n\n'
    'from __future__ import unicode_literals\n'
)
```

and

```
.. testsetup:: 
   from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

but these (of course) don't change the outcome.

How can I test output of non-ASCI characters using Sphinx doctest?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30271479/656912) may be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is due to your `from __future__ import unicode_literals` statement. `print` will implicitly encode Unicode strings to the terminal encoding.  Lacking a terminal, Python 2 will default to the `ascii` codec.

If you skip an explicit `print`, it will work with or without import:

```
>>> def foo():
...  return 'ë'
...
>>> foo()
'\x89'
```

Or:

```
>>> from __future__ import unicode_literals
>>> def foo():
...  return 'ë'
...
>>> foo()
u'\xeb'
```

Then you can test for the escaped representation of the string.

You can also try changing the encoding of `print` itself with `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8`.

Comment: I need a solution that works with explicit `print`. It's also important that I don't have to test for the escaped representation (remember, the tests are visible in the documentation).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, OK, I'm not familiar with Sphinx, but `print` can have its encoding overridden with a `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable.  If you run the tests with `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` it might work.

Comment: Ah, you've put me on the right track. Adding `sys.setdefaultencoding("UTF-8")` to `doctest_global_setup` seems to do the trick — though I really don't understand why!